# PHP MySQL syntax error involving hyphens

Tags: php, mysql

```php
$names = array();
$names['full-name'] = 'John Doe';

$query = "INSERT INTO users (full_name) VALUES ('$names[full-name]')";
$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
```

I have been getting syntax errors whenever I attempt to create a mysql query using an array key that contains a hyphen:

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '-', expecting ']'

How am I able to fix this? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since it hasn't been mentioned yet, here's an another alternative syntax:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO users (full_name) VALUES ('{$names['full-name']}')";
```

Adding the `{}` braces around the variable/array index allows you to quote it as you would if it were outside of the string. The `{}` notation also allows you to embed a multi-dimensional array inside a string, e.g.

```
echo "$x[1][2]";
```

would normally be see as array `$x[1]` followed by literal `[2]` text by PHP, since its array parsing is not 'greedy'. But putting braces aroudn the whole array reference forces PHP parse the entire thing.

Answer (score 2):

a) Take a look at [PDO](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/) (specifically prepared statements), you might be vulnerable to SQL Injection by simply using variables

b) If you just want to get that piece fixed:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO users (full_name) VALUES ('".$names["full-name"]."')";
```

Comment: The above is just an example for my problem. I always use mysql_real_escape_string in my variables before I select, insert, update, or delete in MySQL.

Comment: Using PDO is really simple though, and it's also nice if you're running multiple queries that just differ in the data since prepared statements only need to re-send the new data.

Comment: I am aware of the benefits of PDO including prepared statements and multiple database support. I'm actually going to be learning and using PDO very soon. :)

Answer (score 0):

Having a `-` in a variable is invalid. Use a `_` instead

Comment: It is valid for key names in array.

Comment: I understand that $names is a variable and hyphens aren't allowed but array keys cannot have hyphens? I can create an array key with hyphens in PHP but it's only when I call it in a MySQL query where it starts giving me problems.

Answer (score 0):

```
$query = "INSERT INTO users (full_name) VALUES ('".$names[full-name]."')";
```

Answer (score 0):

`('$names[full-name]')` should be changed to `('$names[\"full-name\"]')`